# Powershell AD-Object DistinguishedName attributes

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to check if an object returned by the `Get-Adcomputer` belongs to a certain group under the `DistinguishedName` property returned. I can't seem to find anything online and looking for some pointers. This attribute contains several different things and I am interested  in the `OU` value in particular.

```
$computer = Get-AdComputer "$computerName"
$computer.DistinguishedName
```

This returns several attributes linked to OU and CN, but I am just interested if one of the OU attributes matches 'Server'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is something you could try if you're just looking for a true/false check

```
$computer = Get-AdComputer "$computerName"
$dn = $computer.DistinguishedName

$dn.Split(',') -match '^ou=.*server'
```

or you could use this to get the whole path

```
# split the distinguishedname into an array of CNs, OUs, etc.
$split = $dn.Split(',')

# setup match variable to signal that we found an object that matches what we are looking for.
$match = $false

# for each item in the array
($split | % {
    # only check this if we have not yet found a match
    # if this line is an OU whose name contains the word 'server'
    if (!$match -and $_ -match '^ou=.*server') {
        # set match to true because we found what we were looking for
        $match = $true
    }
    # if we have found a match, output this and all the rest of the objects to the pipeline
    if ($match) {
        $_
    }
# now we have an array starting at the OU we were looking for
# this join will put the pieces back together into a string so it looks right
}) -join ','
```

note: this will likely not work if any of your objects have a comma in the name.

Comment: Thanks for that, any chance you provide a brief explanation on the second option.